# Neo4j browser runs even when Neo4j is stopped after upgrading to 3.1.0

Tags: browser, neo4j

I run Neo4j on Mac. I've recently updated Neo4j to 3.1.0 and now see the following strange behavior. I have Neo4j stopped

```
$ neo4j status
Neo4j is not running
```

Yet there *is* a process on port `7474`

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:7474
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java     68 root  209u  IPv6 0xb7b22ca733564bf9      0t0  TCP   localhost:7474 (LISTEN)
```

It's process 68.

When I visit http://localhost:7474 I see the Neo4j browser. It's definitely not tunneling into a remote graph, because this works with WiFi off, but it's also *not* pointing at `/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.1.0/libexec/data/databases/graph.db`. If I run

```
neo4j-shell -path /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.1.0/libexec/data/databases/graph.db/
```

it becomes clear I can change these two graphs independently.

Now I can quite easily `sudo kill -9 68` and then start Neo4j. Now `7474` points at the right graph.

But what *is* that original process `68`. Which graph is it pointing to? How can I prevent it from starting itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using https://serverfault.com/questions/285078/how-can-i-prevent-a-process-from-running-under-mac-osx-10-6.

Identify the name of the process from `launchctl`:

```
$ sudo launchctl list | grep "neo4j"
68    0    homebrew.mxcl.neo4j
```

Find the `.plist` file where this name is stored:

```
$ sudo grep -l homebrew.mxcl.neo4j /Library/LaunchDaemons/* /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/*
<path>
```

Permanently unload this file

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w <path>
```